# How to reduce a number to a text input box based on a specific table cell

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table, getelementbyid

How would I reduce the value of:

`<input type="text" id="totalNumber" value="0" name="number" size="5" maxlength="2" disabled>`

based on a number located in a specific cell on a table. The cells are generate via Javascript.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="tableAdjust">
    <table id="myTable" style="width:100%; border: solid black 1px;">
        <tr>
            <th>products</th>
            <th>Desciption</th> 
            <th>Extras</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");//RETRIEVES TABLE
var row = table.insertRow(1);  //INDICATES ROW INSERTION
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //ASSIGNS CELL
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); //ASSIGNS CELL
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2); //ASSIGNS CELL
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3); //ASSIGNS CELL
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4); //ASSIGNS CELL
cell1.innerHTML = cartProducts.name;//ASSIGNS CART PRODUCT NAME
cell2.innerHTML = cartProducts.descript;//ASSIGNS CART PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
cell3.innerHTML = cartProductExtras;//ASSIGNS CART PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
cell4.innerHTML = cartProductQuant;//ASSIGNS CART PRODUCT QUANTITY
cell5.innerHTML = "$ " + cartProductPrice;//ASSIGNS CART ITEM PRICE`
```

HTML INPUTBOX:

```
<input type="text" id="userNumber" name="number" size="2" maxlength="2" value="1" >
```

every time a button is click it adds to the value of the inputbox above and displays the users input in cell 4. I need cell 4's "value" in order to remove it from the table list and reduce the total based on the "value" in that cell.

IMPORTANT: no JQUERY please.

Comment: The question is unclear. Could you show an example? What gets added to what? You mean replaced or added in the cell?

Comment: Is your use-case like this -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Ljufojsy/4/ ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Getting the row from a cell and removing it from its table is also quite simple:

```js
var inputA = document.getElementById("totalNumber");

// Retrieve the value in cell4 and cast it to a number.
var cell4value = parseInt(cell4.innerHTML, 10);

// Delete the row that contains cell4.
var row  = cell4.parentNode;
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);

// Subtract the value that was in cell4 from inputA value.
// Also cast inputA value to a number just in case.
inputA.value = parseInt(inputA.value, 10) - cell4value;
```

---

Initial message:

As I understand, you have 2 HTML inputs: A for total (actually remaining available items?) and B for how many to add to the user's cart when the latter clicks on a button.

You already have a system that automatically adds the value of B to cell4 when the user clicks on the button. Now you want to subtract the same value from value of A? Or the way you describe it, you want to read the result appearing in cell4, and subtract it to the value of A? Note that in the latter case, you will subtract more than needed if the user clicks several times on the button.

I guess you cannot modify the code that already does the addition into B, otherwise it would be trivial to add a line of code to subtract the same amount from A: `document.getElementById("totalNumber").value -= addedAmount;`

To do it the way you describe, let's first read the new content of cell4: `var newCell4qty = parseInt(cell4.innerHTML, 10);`

Then subtract it from A like the initial proposition: `document.getElementById("totalNumber").value -= newCell4qty;`

But it sounds to be more logical to rather read the value of B to use for the subtraction: `var addedAmount2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("userNumber").value, 10);`

Finally, you could need to implement a check if there are enough remaining items before increasing B on button click.

Comment: I need it to retrieve the value if cell 4 then delete the row it's contained in. After that it must subtract the collected value from A.

Comment: Oh do you mean you want to clear the content of cell4? or delete the entire row?

Comment: delete the entire row after collecting cell4 and subtracting the value of total by the collected cell data.